# Downgrade pycharm from 2019.1 to 2018.2 but keep settings

Tags: pycharm

I've decided to not renew my Pycharm license just yet, and of course I now have to install a year older version of the software to continue using it.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to import the settings in Windows?

At startup, I am prompted to complete installation and import settings:

[image: complete installation and import settings]

However when I try to do so on the config folder for 2019.1, I am informed:

"does not appear to be pycharm config folder"

This could be down to no backwards compatibility of config, which seems a bit of a shame, or something else,

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you still have 2019.1 installed? You can export settings from it manually with **File | Export Settings** and import them in 2018.

Comment: @PavelKarateev Hiya, yeah, it's still installed and I was able to launch - just had to jump through a couple of screens and then start an evaluation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I raised this with Jetbrains and they advised:

You can use Export Settings / Import Settings or just copy the config directory: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519 . Most settings are compatible between the releases.

So initially I thought I couldn't launch 2019.1 however when I dismissed the activation/purchase prompt, it then goes on to another screen where you can start up a 30 day evaluation (assuming you haven't already done so on your computer).

Exported and imported and problem solved.